# Contact Pandas DataFrames using a function

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, concatenation

I want to concat multiple pandas `DataFrames` using a function. For example, see the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':['Apple','Yahoo','Google']})
df2 =pd.DataFrame({'A':['Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Google']})

nan_value = 0
combined = pd.concat(dfs, join='outer').fillna(nan_value)
```

But, when I try to put the same in to a function as the following it gives an error: "TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame".

```
def combine_dataframes(df):
    nan_value = 0
    combined = pd.concat(df, join='outer').fillna(nan_value)
    return combined


dfs = [df, df2]
combined = [combine_dataframes(i) for i in dfs]
```

Comment: pd.concat first argument has to be an iterable. You should rewrite the last line of your code into combined = combine_dataframe(dfs).

Comment: @QuantStats: Worked well. Silly me :). If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you , but a comment is sufficient. I am happy to help.